# List of trig identities with proofs

Tags: trigonometry

I want a list of trig identities with available proofs, not just observations. And they cannot be proven by other trig identities without proofs themselves!

For example, we know that:

$$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$

Well, if we use Soh Cah Toa, then we know that :

$$\tan x = \frac{O}{A}, \cos x = \frac{A}{H}, \sin x = \frac{O}{H}$$

$$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{\frac{O}{H}}{\frac{A}{H}}=\frac{O}{A} = \tan x$$

This proof is a proof without other trig identities.

Are there any other identities with proof like this? I want either the proof itself in this article or the link that it is available to show the proof.

## Optional:

You can also make a list of identities without a proof.

Comment: This should be easy to find for yourself, in fact, Wikipedia has whole articles on trig identities.

Comment: @AnonymousPi, I don't actually like Wikipedia, but if you say so... Reason being Wikipedia is not exactly trustable due to its large variety of editors

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) on trig identities is actually very reliable and contains proof or explanation for many identities.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics While this may be true for political/historical/largely opinion based articles, I have found the mathematics department extremely trustable. After all, how can you falsify a theorem and get away with it?

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I appreciate your knowledge of Wikipedia!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "Too broad." There are a lot of trigonometric identities, and it's not hard to find lists in textbooks or online.

Comment: @ArnaudD. maybe a bit too harsh? There aren't many out there... are there? And even so, my question is now answered, so I don't mind anymore. =)

Comment: @simplest_mathematics Well, can you imagine someone retyping all the identities in the Wikipedia page? I'm not even sure one answer would be enough for this, especially if you want proofs... Also if you consider your question answered you could accept the answer.

Comment: That being said, I didn't mean to sound harsh, so sorry if it was the case. And don't take that personally, I just wanted to point out that your question is not really a good fit for this site.

Comment: Okay, I have a low EQ I guess

Comment: The crux here is the precise definition of trig identity and proof. There is a potentially infinite number of them so, as a practical matter, you should have to specify a measure of size of identity so the identities are listed in smaller to larger order with a size cutoff. The precise definitions should also specify when two identities or proofs are essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is great for this. Tons of articles on trig identities. Also, wikipedia is trustable, those comments about how "its free to edit by anyone" isn't necessarily true. Its moderated content.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities